# Correctness of algorithm for finding diameter of graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have heard of algorithm of finding diameter of  unweighted graph using the following algorithm:

```
Algorithm (start_vertex):
    find out the set of vertices S having maximum value of 
        shortest distance from start_vertex.
    ans = 0;
    for each vertex v in S
        temp = 0;
        for each vertex u in graph G:
            temp = max(temp, shortest distance between u and v).
        ans = temp;
    return ans;
```

This algorithm works in linear time for finding diameter of graph. Can anyone prove its correctness or prove it is false

Comment: Recursion would seem to be the best solution for this. I will try to come up with an answer.

Comment: "This algorithm works in linear time" It actually doesn't, as it contains a double loop on the vertices, potentially.

Comment: If you are actually thinking about a very similar statement that is true in trees, the following link might be of interest: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work

Comment: Can you give me counter example for graph with 3,4,5,6,8 nodes.Because i cannot prove it incorrect for graph with these nodes

Comment: This question is from an active coding competition: https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/DEVLDISC

Answer (score 3):

A counter-example:

[image]

Obviously, graph diameter is 4 (distance from A to C),
but with starting vertex B you will have S = {D},
and all vertices are within range 3 from D.

This graph contains 7 vertices.
You can add extra vertices (inside the triangle) without breaking the counter-example to get a graph of size 8, 9, ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counter-example:

[image: Graph]

Obviously, the graph has diameter 16 (from c to d).
If you start at a, the set S contains of solely b. The vertex with maximum minimal distance to b is e. Hence, the algorithm would return the graph diameter 11.

Comment: i forgot to add it is an unweighted graph. Can you give me counter example for graph with 3,4,5,6,8 nodes

Comment: Looks as if the algorithm is correct for unweighted graphs. See the link to CS SE in the comments.

Comment: If I understand right, the algorithm on SC SE is for trees. I think your counterexample can be modified: for an edge with weight k make k-1 nodes in between and all new edges should have weight 1. The algorithm would not find the diameter, if  I see it correctly.